# How can I make a program run at startup in only one definite session that uses the same desktop environment as others?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, startup

I installed (aware of the risks) software from the Elementary Team PPAs and I set up a Pantheon Shell session, which is based on Gnome. I would like to have Plank (a fork of Docky) to run at startup for this session, but not when I'm logging into Unity or the Classic Gnome session. Adding Plank to the Startup Applications list makes it run in every Gnome-based session. Thanks for your help!

Comment: just a suggestion but would a bash script to check for the existence of unity and if not run plank suffice? I'm not posting this as an answer as I don't know how to check for a specific process by name in bash. But you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Startup applications are defined by .desktop files that live in ~/.local/share/autostart, according to the [Desktop Application Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).

They optional setting to limit them to one or more desktop environments, e.g.

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;XFCE;LXDE;
```

Alternatively you can use

```
NotShowIn=...
```

to exclude this app from the listed desktop environments.

Only one of these keys, either OnlyShowIn or NotShowIn, may appear in a single .desktop file. (That was a direct quote from the spec.)

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you're doing qualifies as a separate desktop environment...

Comment: Well, GNOME and Unity are separate environments; but I suspect both Classic GNOME and Plank would show up as "GNOME".

Answer (score -1):

Find the auto startup files (eg conky.desktop for conky)  in

```
~/.local/share/autostart  OR

~/.config/autostart (In arch based distros)
```

Otherwise if preventing normal apps from appearing in another desktop environment ( those with more than one DE) , find the files in

```
/usr/share/applications
(also check .local/share/applications in your home folder)
```

and identify the file name of the applications you don't want to appear under your present DE eg vlc.desktop

Find this line

```
OnlyShowIn=
```

and delete the DE you don't want. If there isn't this line, add it and add also the DE. eg

```
 OnlyShowIn=KDE or NotShowIn=GNOME,XFCE;
```